# Многопоточность и организация вывода данных

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Изучаю многопоточность и столкнулся с проблемой, ведет себя не понятным образом.

Я сканирую сеть и получаю список пингующихся хостов в сети.
Затем использую **Parallel.ForEach** , чтобы быстро получить данные об этих хостах.

```
ParallelOptions opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 };
var ping_success_ips = PingSuccess().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var db = new LanScannerModel();
Computer computer = new Computer();
Parallel.ForEach(ping_success_ips, opts, ip =>
{
    computer.Status = true;
    computer.Os = WMI.GetOs(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.Mac = WMI.GetMacAddress(ip);
    computer.IP = ip;
    computer.Hostname = WMI.GetHostName(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.ONTime = DateTime.Now;                  
    Console.WriteLine(computer.IP + "   "+ computer.Mac + " " + computer.Os + " " + computer.Hostname);
});
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но происходит очень странное явление и записи дублируются, я так понимаю что какие-то данные приходят быстро, а какие-то с опозданием и происходит эта  неразбериха.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Вот методы из класса WMI

```
public static string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    string macAddress = string.Empty;
    System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pProcess.Start();
    string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
    if (substrings.Length >= 8)
    {
        macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2))
                 + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6]
                 + "-" + substrings[7] + "-"
                 + substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
        return macAddress;
    }

    else
    {
        return "not found";
    }
}
public static async Task<object> GetHostName(string ipAddress)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
            if (entry != null)
            {
                return entry.HostName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return "0";
        }
        return null;

    });
}
```

Comment: на том скриншоте где вы пометили "дублирующиеся записи" отличается computer.Hostname

Comment: Вот зачем вы сначала делаете `Task.Run` - а потом ждете через `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: вы меняете одну и ту же сущность. Занесите ```Computer computer = new Computer();``` внутрь вашего цикла

Comment: @pavel-mayorov  там все в порядке список выдается без дублирования. Могу добавить его сюда, чтобы вы глянули.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Вы были правы, проблема в этом. Можете написать в ответ. Только я не совсем понял почему. Я же типа перезаписываю данные в этой сущности, а так получаются создаю каждый раз новую. Не пойму в чем разница.

Comment: @shatoidil разница в том, что в первом случае ты разделяешь этот ресурс между потоками, и каждый из них модифицирует его, перезаписывая изменения других. Здесь нет прозрачного copy-on-write при передаче объекта в метод, выполняющийся в контексте другого потока. Если ты используешь ссылку на объект, значит меняться будет объект по этой ссылке, в этом потоке или в другом - не важно.

Comment: добавил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы меняете одну и ту же сущность. Занесите `Computer computer = new Computer();` внутрь вашего цикла 
Это типичная проблема (а может и не проблема) для начинающих разбираться в многопоточности.

Возьмем ваш код

```
Computer computer = new Computer();
Parallel.ForEach(ping_success_ips, opts, ip =>
{
    computer.Status = true;
    computer.Os = WMI.GetOs(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.Mac = WMI.GetMacAddress(ip);
    computer.IP = ip;
    computer.Hostname = WMI.GetHostName(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.ONTime = DateTime.Now;                  
    ///////  Метка 1
    Console.WriteLine(computer.IP + "   "+ computer.Mac + " " + computer.Os + " " + computer.Hostname);
});
```

Вы же запускаете его параллельно, верно? То есть несколько потоков одновременно его выполняют. А теперь представьте, что 2 потока идут одновременно, и одновременно достигают строки с меткой 1. То есть каждый из 2 потоков что то изменял в вашей сущности (она ж одна у вас для всех потоков), но в итоге оба потока дошли до вывода сущности на консоль. И дальше они одновременно пытаются вывести её на консоль, и если никакие другие потоки сущность не меняют в этот момент, то вывод 2 раза одной и той же сущности даст один и тот же результат в консоли - потому строки продублировались.

Что я вам предложил: я предложил создавать для каждого потока отдельный экземпляр компьютера.

```
Parallel.ForEach(ping_success_ips, opts, ip =>
{
    Computer computer = new Computer();
    computer.Status = true;
    computer.Os = WMI.GetOs(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.Mac = WMI.GetMacAddress(ip);
    computer.IP = ip;
    computer.Hostname = WMI.GetHostName(ip).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    computer.ONTime = DateTime.Now;                  
    ///////  Метка 1
    Console.WriteLine(computer.IP + "   "+ computer.Mac + " " + computer.Os + " " + computer.Hostname);
});
```

То есть теперь потоки работают каждый со своим экземпляром, и не влияют друг на друга. И теперь в метке 1 два разных потока будут выводить на консоль РАЗНЫЕ экземпляры компьютеров, потому дублирования нет.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, из меня учитель так себе :)

Comment: +1 - объяснил удовлетворительно

Comment: @Igor спасибо :)